# React frontend response error from flask backend

Tags: python, reactjs, rest, flask, fetch-api

I'm creating a react app that utilizes a flask backend that serves as a REST API. Unfortunately, I've been having issues with the fetch command, in that it always seems to say fetch failed loading: [method]. The backend seems to handle the request fine.

**127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2021 21:10:35] "GET /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200** -

I've tried the request in postman and it works fine. I'm using a proxy for `HTTP://localhost:5000` in my `package.json` so I don't think this is a CORS problem, and I've also tried using flask_cors to no avail. Has anyone experienced something like this before with fetch API? I'm fairly new to javascript so there may be something I'm not noticing.

Thanks.

Users.py (blueprint)

```
from . import bp
from flask import jsonify, request, make_response

@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
return jsonify({'status': 'success'})
```

**init**.py (blueprint)

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('rest', __name__)

from . import users
```

init.py (app)

```
def create_app():
    from .config import Config

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    mail = Mail(app)


    from .models import db, Visitor, User
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    @app.shell_context_processor
    def make_shell_context():
        return {"config": Config, "db": db, "Visitor": Visitor, "User": User}

    #jwt.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')
    return app
```

Request (from react button event handler)

```
    export default function LoginUser(props) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    function handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target

        switch (name) {
            case 'email':
                setUser({ ...user, email: value });
                break;

            case 'password':
                setUser({ ...user, password: value });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {

        fetch('/api/login').then(res => res.json()).then().catch(error => console.log('error'))
    }

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="LoginEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter email"
                    name="email"
                    onBlur={handleChange} />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="LoginPassword">
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    name="password"
                    onBlur={handleChange} />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Browser error (Brave)

```
handleSubmit @ main.chunk.js:781
callCallback @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24274
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24323
invokeGuardedCallback @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24383
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24398
executeDispatch @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28633
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28665
processDispatchQueue @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28678
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28689
(anonymous) @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28900
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ vendors~main.chunk.js:42585
batchedEventUpdates @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24072
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ vendors~main.chunk.js:28899
attemptToDispatchEvent @ vendors~main.chunk.js:26382
dispatchEvent @ vendors~main.chunk.js:26300
unstable_runWithPriority @ vendors~main.chunk.js:56804
runWithPriority$1 @ vendors~main.chunk.js:31680
discreteUpdates$1 @ vendors~main.chunk.js:42602
discreteUpdates @ vendors~main.chunk.js:24084
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ vendors~main.chunk.js:26266
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

`fetch('/api/login').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(error => console.log('error'))` to `fetch('/api/login').then(res => res.json()).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log('error'))`.

Because using fetch, your 'res' is just an HTTP response, not the actual JSON. So you need res.json() to get the JSON body.

#### Edit version

Change `<Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>` to `<Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>`. Also add `e.preventDefault()` in the handleSubmit function to prevent the page from refreshing.

Note: You should pass your user in api login

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have already tried this, will edit post

Comment: Yes, the post is going through to my backend with a 200 response code, so should be correct

Comment: Ok, I posted the component

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work, still the same error.

Comment: And just like that, e.preventDefault(); does the trick, works like a charm. Thank you, I really appreciate the help I've been beating my head into a wall over this

Comment: Hahahahaha no problem